# Different layouts in nested Angular states with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My application has four logical states:

```
pages.list      (lists pages)
pages.create    (create a new page)
pages.item      (show a single page)
pages.item.edit (edit a single page)
```

The states `pages.list` and `pages.item` share one base template (a traditional three column layout), but the states `pages.create` and `pages.item.edit` have a totally different template (a full-page editor).

What's the best way to express this with ui-router?

Answer (score 5):

I would say that using `abstract states` is the way to go. In [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views), they clearly outline the benefits and some of them fit your use case pretty nicely (emphasis mine):

> Some examples of how you might use an abstract state are:
>
> - **To prepend a url to all child state urls.**
> - **To insert a template with its own ui-view(s) that its child states will populate.**
>
>   - Optionally assign a controller to the template. The controller must pair to a template.
>   - Additionally, inherit $scope objects down to children, just understand that this happens via the view hierarchy, not the state hierarchy.
> - To provide resolved dependencies via resolve for use by child states.
> - To provide inherited custom data via data for use by child states or an event listener.
> - To run an onEnter or onExit function that may modify the application in someway.
> - Any combination of the above.

With that understanding, your app can be structured as follows:

---

### STEP 1

Create two templates that your pages can use. Let's call them `three_columns.html` and `one_column.html`. For 3-column layout, make sure you name your `ui-view` accordingly:

```
<!-- three_columns snippet -->
...
<body>
    <div ui-view="left"></div>
    <div ui-view="middle"></div>
    <div ui-view="right"></div>
</body>
```

Then, one-column template:

```
<!-- one_column snippet -->
...
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

---

### STEP 2

Declare two `abstract states`. Let's called them `oneCol` and `threeCols`. Note that since both of them declare `url: '/pages'`, all inheriting child states will have `/pages` automatically prepended to their own URLs.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('oneCol', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/pages',
    templateUrl: 'layouts/one_column.html'
}).state('threeCols', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/pages',
    templateUrl: 'layouts/three_columns.html'
});
```

---

### STEP 3

Declare your states which extend `abstract states` above. Suppose we call them `list`, `create`, `view`, and `edit`. Here, `threeCols.list` and `threeCols.view` will have to declare 3 `templateUrl`s, one for each named `ui-view`. On the other hand, `oneCol.create` and `oneCol.edit` will declare their unnamed `templateUrl` normally. The convention I usually use is to create a folder specific to each state, since it's good for organizing sub-view templates:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('threeCols.list', {
    url: '/list',
    controller: 'ListCtrl',
    views: {
        'left': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/list/leftbar.html'
        },
        'middle': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/list/content.html'
        },
        'right': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/list/rightbar.html'
        }
    }
}).state('oneCol.create', {
    url: '/create',
    controller: 'CreateCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'modules/create/content.html'
}).state('threeCols.view', {
    url: '/view',
    controller: 'ViewCtrl',
    views: {
        'left': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/view/leftbar.html'
        },
        'middle': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/view/content.html'
        },
        'right': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/view/rightbar.html'
        }
    }
}).state('oneCol.edit', {
    url: '/edit',
    controller: 'EditCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'modules/edit/content.html'
});
```

With this, now your URLs will look like what you expected: `/pages/list`, `/pages/create`, `/pages/view`, `/pages/edit`. You can also create and reuse templates as much as you like.

Comment: This answer helped me understand and implement the change in my app that the OP needed. Nice & self-explanatory :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually define my routes based on view, not really based on the model. For example, given your simple explanation above, I would use the following:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('pages.list', { url: '/list', controller: 'ListCtrl', templateUrl: 'threecol.html' })
    .state('pages.create', { url: '/create', controller: 'CreateCtrl', templateUrl: 'create.html' })
    .state('pages.item', { url: '/:itemId', controller: 'ItemCtrl', templateUrl: 'threecol.html' })
    .state('pages.edit', { url: '/:itemId/edit', controller: 'EditCtrl', templateUrl: 'edit.html' });
```

Essentially then you would use `threecol.html` to define your common three column layout. `create.html` and `edit.html` would be your full pages.

If you wanted a more abstract approach defined around the layout types, you could also create abstract parent states to define the layout itself. For example you could have:

```
threecol.list
threecol.item
fullpage.create
fullpage.edit
```

If you made `threecol` and `fullpage` abstract states, you could define the commonly used layout markup, and just insert the appropriate `<div ui-view=""></div>` where desired. That way you could use different content template files for `list` and `item` for example.

Comment: hmm… but doesn't the first option make it impossible to take advantage of any view nesting (ex, because `create.html` and `edit.html` can't inherit from a `full-screen.html` template)? And doesn't the second option make nesting URL routes impossible (ex, it's hard — in any reuseable way — to prefix each of the URLs with `/pages`)?

Comment: You might need to be more specific about your needs. Why can't you just prefix `/pages` in the second option?